# Send mail in Lotus Notes using python

Tags: python, email, lotus-notes

i need help for send a mail in the Lotus Notes using python, appear that the win32com can do it, but i don't found any complete example or tutorial. My idea is a simple function like it:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import smtplib

def SendMail(subject, text, user):
    session = Dispatch('Lotus.NotesSession')
    session.Initialize('???')
    db = session.getDatabase("", "")
    db.OpenMail();
```

Some suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Below is some code that I have used for this purpose for several years:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

import os, uuid
import itertools as it

from win32com.client import DispatchEx
import pywintypes # for exception

def send_mail(subject,body_text,sendto,copyto=None,blindcopyto=None,
              attach=None):
    session = DispatchEx('Lotus.NotesSession')
    session.Initialize('your_password')

    server_name = 'your/server'
    db_name = 'your/database.nsf'

    db = session.getDatabase(server_name, db_name)
    if not db.IsOpen:
        try:
            db.Open()
        except pywintypes.com_error:
            print( 'could not open database: {}'.format(db_name) )

    doc = db.CreateDocument()
    doc.ReplaceItemValue("Form","Memo")
    doc.ReplaceItemValue("Subject",subject)

    # assign random uid because sometimes Lotus Notes tries to reuse the same one
    uid = str(uuid.uuid4().hex)
    doc.ReplaceItemValue('UNIVERSALID',uid)

    # "SendTo" MUST be populated otherwise you get this error: 
    # 'No recipient list for Send operation'
    doc.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", sendto)

    if copyto is not None:
        doc.ReplaceItemValue("CopyTo", copyto)
    if blindcopyto is not None:
        doc.ReplaceItemValue("BlindCopyTo", blindcopyto)

    # body
    body = doc.CreateRichTextItem("Body")
    body.AppendText(body_text)

    # attachment 
    if attach is not None:
        attachment = doc.CreateRichTextItem("Attachment")
        for att in attach:
            attachment.EmbedObject(1454, "", att, "Attachment")

    # save in `Sent` view; default is False
    doc.SaveMessageOnSend = True
    doc.Send(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subject = "test subject"
    body = "test body"
    sendto = ['abc@def.com',]
    files = ['/path/to/a/file.txt','/path/to/another/file.txt']
    attachment = it.takewhile(lambda x: os.path.exists(x), files)

    send_mail(subject, body, sendto, attach=attachment)
```

Comment: Hi Bernie,
this code worked perfectly. Solved my problems, very thanks for your help!

Comment: Alright. You're welcome. Cheers, and happy coding to you

Comment: Hi Bernie, I did local tests in my PC and it works, but when I tested in the other PC the same not work. I received the following message: "Exception occured.... cannot open database names.nsf". I dont understand, because the configuration of Lotus Notes is the same of the other machine. I checked, the database is in workspace of Lotus Notes, to the server I am using "". Have you some idea about this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I can help. I assume you have verified, for the other PC, that the server name is what you expect it to be.

Comment: I got error on this line `session = DispatchEx('Lotus.NotesSession')`, error message: `dispatch=pythoncom.CoCreateInstanceEx(clsid, None, clsctx, serverInfo, (pythoncom.IID_IDispatch,))[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

If your company is set up such a way that a host IP address and Port is sufficient to send an email, then use the following:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def emailReport(attach_path,file_name,From,to,cc=None):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = file_name
    msg['From'] = From
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(to) 
    msg['CC'] = ", ".join(cc)
    msg.attach(MIMEText("****Body of your email****\n"))

    #For multiple attachments repeat/loop  the following:
    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(open(attach_path.format(file_name), "rb").read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s' % file_name)
    msg.attach(part)
    #Repeat stops here....

    s = smtplib.SMTP(host='xxx.xxx.xx.x',port=xx) #Enter your IP and port here
    s.sendmail(From,to+cc,msg.as_string())
    s.quit()



to=['Person1@email.com', 'Person2@email.com']
cc=['Person3@email.com', 'Person4@email.com']
From='Your@email.com'
attach_path=r'C:\Users\Desktop\Temp'
file_name='Test.xlsx'

emailReport(attach_path,file_name,From,to,cc)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, Your code works like a charm. I wasted lot of time debugging error.