# Mising "Lotus Notes Automation Classes"

Tags: python, lotus-notes, win32com

I am trying to create a lotus notes email from python, I started with something basic and I can't connect to the lotus notes client

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import smtplib

session = Dispatch("Lotus.Notessession")
```

This generates this error

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221164, 'Clase no registrada', None, None)
```

I tried this

```
from win32com.client import makepy
makepy.GenerateFromTypeLibSpec('Lotus Domino Objects')
makepy.GenerateFromTypeLibSpec('Lotus Notes Automation Classes')
```

Whith this result

```
Could not locate a type library matching 'Lotus Notes Automation Classes'
[Finished in 2.0s]
```

However, from VBA I can access and create emails without problem ...
Can anybody help me? THANKS

My Config:

```
WINDOWS 10
Python 3.7.4
Lotus Notes 9.0.1FP10 SHF252
```

Regards

Josse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065191/send-mail-in-lotus-notes-using-python ?

Answer (score 0):

The Notes software is 32-bit. Is your Python environment 64-bit?  If so, the Lotus classes are probably not registered for 64 bit. See [my answer to this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322360/cant-create-lotus-notes-objects/31323051#31323051).

Also, there is a difference between Lotus Domino Objects, and Lotus Notes Automation Classes. The former are COM classes and are accessed via Lotus.NotesSession and can be made to work on 64-bit (mostly) if they are properly registered - but are [not supported on 64-bit](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21454291). The latter are OLE classes and are accessed via Notes.NotesSession, and I don't think they can be made to work on 64-bit (but I might be wrong) and are also not supported on 64-bit.